# nebula release plugin no tag pushed

Tags: java, git, gradle

We have a Spring Boot project that we are versioning with the [nebula-release-plugin](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/nebula-release-plugin). (v6.0.0)

The versioning logic is working well but when we are running the `candidate` or `final` tasks, no tags are created or pushed into git (we're using gitlab).

```
<br/>
D:\dev\workspace\my-project>gradle final -x test
Inferred project: my-project, version: 1.2.0                           
:prepare UP-TO-DATE                        
:releaseCheck                
:finalSetup                 
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE                                                                                                                                               
:processResources UP-TO-DATE      
:classes UP-TO-DATE      
:enunciate UP-TO-DATE      
:findMainClass                 
:jar                 
:bootRepackage                                                                                                                                                             
:assemble                 
:check                 
:build                 
:release                 
:postRelease                 
:final
```

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

What could be the cause of this? For tag creation and pushing is there more configuration to be done besides just applying the plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused by the fact that we had the `release.disableGitChecks` property set to `true` in gradle.properties.

Comment: Could I use this to prevent the tags to be pushed by nebula itself?